# Manage authorized_keys using cfengine

Tags: cfengine

I'm trying to manage OpenSSH's `authorized_keys` using `cfengine`.

It's easy to add/delete special lines in `authorized_keys`, but I cannot figure out how to delete unwanted lines.

e.g. I need to add `pubkey_one`, `pubkey_two`, `pubkey_three` to `authorized_key`, then delete any lines not listed above.

Any help or hint would appreciated :-)

Answer (score 2):

For this particular case, I think the easiest would be to use `edit_defaults => empty`, so that CFEngine starts from an empty file. Something like this:

```
files:
  "/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys"
    edit_defaults => empty,
    edit_line => add_authorized_keys;
```

Note that `body edit_defaults empty` is defined in cfengine_stdlib.cf, so you need to include it in your `inputs`.

Comment: You are right. For my particular case, empty file first is a good solution. But what if I want to get notified that there's unwanted lines, instead of just deleting unwanted lines?

Comment: You could add an "action" attribute to the files: promise, for example something like `action => log_repaired("/some/file", "Had to repair authorized_keys")`. See https://github.com/cfengine/copbl/blob/master/cfengine_stdlib.cf#L717for log_repaired.